# How to use python virtual environment in another computer

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have created an virtual environment by using `virtualenv pyenv` in my linux system. Now i want to use the virtual environment in another computer. Can i direct copy the virtual environment and use it in another computer? Or need i do something to set up it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should not. The other computer can have a different operating system, other packages or package versions installed, so copying the files will not work.

The point of a virtual environment is to be able to replicate it everywhere you need it.

Make a script which installs all necessary dependencies from a `requirements.txt` file and use it.

Use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to get the list of all python packages installed. Then install the dependencies in another virtual environment on another computer using `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

If you want the exact environment, including system packages, on another computer, use Docker.

Comment: Your answer assumes he has internet on the other computer. What if he doesn't have that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use copy and paste it in another directory or computer, but its not a best way to use virtualenv.
you better notedown your requirements in any txt file like **requirement.txt** and run the 
use `pip freeze > requirement.txt` to write all the requirements in `requirement.txt`

script using `pip`.

```
pip install -r requirement.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. First i run the command pip freeze > requirement.txt and when i moved the code to other pc i did: pip install -r requirement.txt.

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to make sure that everything including your OS are the same in both computers then you can use virtual box and vagrant on top to setup a virtual box and then create your virtualenv using either requirements or any other way to reproduce it.

https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/