# virtual environment is not activating after re-installation of virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

Previously I had Virtual Environment installed on my system. I created two different VirtualEnv for two different projects I was working on.
I use to activate one of these virtual environment and would start working on project.
Recently my system got corrupted and I upgraded the OS after copying all projects and virtual environments. I copied the project files and virtual environments back to my system and installed virtual environment.

Set PYTHONHOME='/usr/lib/python3' in .bashrc

Now when I activated one of the copied environment and tried to run python manage.py runserver, I got below error

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Running pip inside this virtual env is throwing same error.

Please suggest me what I need to so that my project can work as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not recommended to move a virual environment i.e. to a new system, or a different OS installation - [A SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26399797/1384641).

Good practice is to generate the requirements list (installed Python packages) - while virtual environment is active, execute:

```
$(venv)  pip freeze > requirements_venv.txt
```

On the new installation (delete the copied venv if you have it), setup a fresh virtual environment using Python 3, activate it, and then install the python packages:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv/
$ source env/bin/activate
$ pip install -r requirements_venv.txt
```

---

**Probable issue**:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**States, the system's Python 3 is trying to load something that was written for some other Python version i.e. Python 2.x**.

Most probable reason for the errors you're getting can be,

- Created virtual environment with a different python version.
- Improper `PYTHONPATH`,
- Not restarting the terminal after setting `PYTHONPATH`

---

**Solution/way-out**:

First check if you're able to get into the Python shell i.e. execute `python` or `python3` command in the terminal.
If not, unset the `PYTHONPATH` in `.bashrc`, and execute the following commands in the terminal (or whatever the exact path is on your system):

```
# export PYTHONHOME=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/
# export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.5
```

Now again try to start the Python shell i.e. i.e. execute `python` or `python3` command in the terminal, you must get something similar like below:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 17 2016, 00:00:00) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

With Python shell working, most probably you may not face the posted issue - if you do, delete the copied virtual environment and install and new one (as stated at the top).

Answer (score 0):

Is python correctly installed?

run python in cmd and check the path also

If some dependencies are broken then Try reinstall it correctly

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7

sudo apt-get update
```

Now try to use virtualenv by

```
pip install virtualenv <name>
 or 
pip install virtualenv .
```

active it by source ./bin/activate

Comment: So I need to recreate the virtualenv, I can't reuse the previous virtual environments?

Comment: @User42 Is there any core dependencies in that env? If they are normal package try to install it them in this new virtualenv.

Comment: @User42 see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438681/duplicate-virtualenv and this https://github.com/edwardgeorge/virtualenv-clone

Answer (score 0):

Virtual environments uses some symlinks back to the source python installation in order to share resources and binaries. I think it is very doubtful that you should be able to move a virtual environment to a new/different system and have it working out of the box.