# Python 3.9.6 virtual environment: different packages shown in two different machines

Tags: python-venv, python-3.9

I am a bit confused about the python Virtual environment. I thought you use them so you can make sure that the same packages and setting can run in two different machines. Here's my problem. I have installed and activate a python VENV in a Virtual machine running Centos 7. I have created a git repository that contains a django app called CTR and a python VENV:

> CTR  python39-RIGS-venv  README.md

when activated:

```
source python39-RIGS-venv/bin/activate

pip3 list
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
asgiref            3.4.1
certifi            2021.10.8
charset-normalizer 2.0.7
Django             3.2.9
idna               3.3
pip                21.3.1
pytz               2021.3
requests           2.26.0
setuptools         56.0.0
sqlparse           0.4.2
urllib3            1.26.7
```

I have then downloaded the same repo in my mac, activated the python VENV and this is the result:

```
source python39-RIGS-venv/bin/activate

pip3 list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        21.1.3
setuptools 56.0.0
```

Why not all packages installed are visible in the mac VENV? I thought that was the purpose of python VENV. Make sure you can run same configuration in different machine. What am I missing here? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

After a more accurate search I have found out the question has been already answered here:

[How to use python virtual environment in another computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399754/how-to-use-python-virtual-environment-in-another-computer)

I will leave the link here to help other people with my same dilemma.