# Error extracting python virtual environment

Tags: dockerfile, tar, pyenv-virtualenv

I have a venv for python 3.10 containing some packages. Whenever I want to extract it using `tar -xf env.310.tar.gz` the following errors will prevent running my docker script:

```
tar: 3.10/lib/terminfo: Cannot open: File exists
tar: 3.10/lib/python3.1: Cannot create symlink to 'python3.10': File exists
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

How can I tel tar to ignore the errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use python virtual environment in another computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399754/how-to-use-python-virtual-environment-in-another-computer)

Comment: @gre_gor: No! That question is based on installing packages inside requirements.txt from the internet when building docker image. But I'm trying to extract the local venv into the image.

Comment: No, the question is about moving the venv folder.